# div de un mismo tamaño dentro de una consulta (while)

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

Estoy generando una consulta. pero cada uno de los div son de diferentes tamaños. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que los div generados tengan las mismas dimensiones o tamaños?

```
<?php
                while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){

                    $dolar_consulta = $conexion->query('select * from dolar')or die($conexion->error);
                $dolar = mysqli_fetch_row($dolar_consulta);
?>
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4" data-aos="fade-up">
                <div class="block-4 text-center border">
                  <figure class="block-4-image">
                    <a href="shop-single.php?id=<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>"><img  src="images/<?php echo $fila['imagen']; ?>" alt="" <?php echo utf8_encode( $fila['nombre']); ?>" class="img-fluid"></a>
                  </figure>
                  <div class="block-4-text p-4">
                 
                  <h6><a href="shop-single.php?id=<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>"><?php echo utf8_encode($fila['nombre']); ?></a></h6>
                    <p class="mb-0"><?php echo utf8_encode($fila['descripcion0']) ; ?></p>
                    <p class="text-primary font-weight-bold"><?php echo number_format($fila['precio']*$dolar[1]);  ?>  Bs.</p>
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es correcto lo que te indica "Suhshinron DC", pero si sigues con problemas, yo haría lo siguiente:
Aquí he puesto una clase diferente a la que tu indicas, porque es un ejemplo.

```
div.wrapper {
    min-height: 400px; 
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

min-height tiene prioridad sobre los valores max-height y height;
max-height sobrescribe height, pero no sobrescribe min-height.
De esta manera, creo que siempre tendrías el mismo "height".
Pero esto quizás no funcione cuando cambies de resolución.

En ese caso, podrías recurrir a un div contenedor con la propiedad "Display Flex".

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-container > div {
  height:120px;
}
```

Esto lo probé una sola vez y me ha funcionado.
Disculpa que no te de mejores respuestas, soy novato.

Answer (score 1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A la hora de crear los divs, ponles siempre el mismo nombre de la clase y si es posible genera siempre los div con JavaScript, así es mucho mas intuitivo y rápido.